# How to apply a animation as default pose?

Tags: rigging

I have a rig on an ogre and I want to cross import some mixamo animations. But because Im exporting a A-Pose model to mixamo, the imported animations have a faulty arm offset.

- the default pose of my ogre is a A-Pose in Edit-Mode
- I have a T-Pose animation action in Pose-Mode

How do I apply the animation action T-Pose so that my rest pose is no longer the A-Pose.

**A-Pose in Edit-Mode**

[image: A-Pose in Edit-Mode]

**T-Pose in Pose-Mode**

[image]

Comment: I think I need some clarification, I don't have Pose in Edit mode
Pose is a separate mode
1. I went to pose mode in the T-Pose animation
2. Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as Rest Pose
3. resulting in this https://i.imgur.com/cOZd53R.png
thank you for your time :)
the new bone position is now set to T-Pose but the mesh did not follow along in edit mode

Comment: sorry yes I meant once in Pose mode. For the mesh, maybe you could duplicate the Armature modifier and apply one of the 2?

Comment: thank you soooo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the mesh, duplicate the *Armature* modifier and apply one. For the armature, switch to *Pose* mode and header menu > *Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as Rest Pose*, or shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: when I duplicated one armature modifier and applied it the arms had an offset again
Idk why exactly

Comment: isn't it fixed once you apply the pose? Also, you should still have the weight paint as you still have the vertex groups, weight paint is just a way to assign vertices to vertex group and if you apply the Armature modifier it won't remove the vertex groups. If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I will test if for you once more ^^ u are completely right
I will delete my somewhat incorrect answer